# "'C' is not identical to 'UInt8'" in Swift when using += operator

Tags: swift

Consider the following code, my attempt to implement Haskell's `Data.List.concat` in Swift:

```
protocol Concatenable: SequenceType {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init()
}

extension Array: Concatenable {}

func concatenate<S: SequenceType, C: Concatenable where S.Generator.Element == C>(seq: S) -> C {
    var result = C()
    for elem in seq {
        result = result + elem
    }
    return result
}
```

This works well, but if the line `result = result + elem` is instead changed to `result += elem`, I get the error "'C' is not identical to 'UInt8'". My understanding is that `+=` is just syntactic sugar, not a separate operator on its own, so `result = result + elem` should be absolutely equivalent to `result += elem`. Either this assumption is incorrect or this is a bug in Swift. (And where is `UInt8` coming from? I know what this type is, but why does the Swift compiler think this code has anything to do with it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `+=` is a separate operator, so you have to add it to your protocol definition:

```
protocol Concatenable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func +=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
    init()
}
```

The Swift error messages can be misleading. Perhaps the compiler tries to use *any* known
`+=` definition, e.g.

```
func +=(inout lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8)
```

by converting the arguments to `UInt8`.

Note that you get a similar functionality with the built-in library function `join()`:

```
let foo = join([], [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
println(foo)
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of `join`, but as I said, this is an exercise in learning Swift, not an attempt to create a truly usable library of functions. In fact, I've even re-implemented some of the built-in functions just to see how they (might) have been done.